# How to download from the XML url using python

Tags: python, xml, python-requests

- I am trying to extract from the URL
- I am trying to get the download from the `first` URL which file_type file_type is DLTINS

Below is the code

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
response = requests.get("https://registers.esma.europa.eu/solr/esma_registers_firds_files/select?q=*&fq=publication_date:%5B2021-01-17T00:00:00Z+TO+2021-01-19T23:59:59Z%5D&wt=xml&indent=true&start=0&rows=100")
root = ET.fromstring(response.text)
```

I am getting like object `<xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree at 0x7fd745e84da0>`

In `response.text` I am getting everything in string

Comment: share the xml so we can have a look. share your code as well

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is.  You got an `ElementTree` object--that's what you want isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


response = requests.get('https://registers.esma.europa.eu/solr/esma_registers_firds_files/select?q=*&fq=publication_date:%5B2021-01-17T00:00:00Z+TO+2021-01-19T23:59:59Z%5D&wt=xml&indent=true&start=0&rows=100')
root = ET.fromstring(response.text)
for i in root.findall('result'):
    for j in i.findall('doc'):
        for k in j:
            link = j.find('.//str[@name="download_link"]').text
            print(link)
            req = requests.get(link)
```

Comment: The zip file is not downloading

Comment: got it I should be doing open('dfd.zip', 'wb').write(req.content)